# How to Debug DotNetNuke Project Template in Visual Studio Express Versions (2012/2013)

Tags: debugging, dotnetnuke

Please help me how to debug DotNetNuke template project in Visual Studio 2013 Web Express Version.

Previously I used Visual Studio 2012 Professional Version and it can be available "Attach to Process" feature under Debug tab. So it is easy to debug. Now I cannot see "Attach to Process" in Express version (2012 & 2013). Please tell me a way to debug DotNetNuke project template in express versions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

VS Express 2013 for Web doesn't have the attach feature - just the VS Express 2013 for Desktop version.

It is possible to run the full DNN source code in the Visual Studio using the built in web server (IIS Express).  Then you could add your module project to that solution. This would allow you to do the 1-click debugging in Visual Studio.  Might be a bit of work to get that environment setup properly.

If it were me, I would figure out how to get a copy of VS Professional so you can do the attach.